# Best practice for Appium to find element

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-android

I have 2 native apps(not hybrid or react native), they share same design, one is for Android(JAVA) and the other is for IOS(OC). Now I need to make some test for these 2 apps. I am trying to do this with Appium.

Appium provide lots of methods to find a element. To write a test case for both app, it seems I can use `AccessibilityId`. If I ask developer to add same `AccessibilityId` to both android and ios project, then I can make the same test code work with both apps. Does this the best practice? This may bring lots of effort to both android and ios develop team to add `AccessibilityId`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the use of accessibility IDs is the preferred method. It is not necessary for the IDs to match across platforms.

You can define these elements with FindBy tags in your class definition as follows:

```
@iOSFindBy(id = "send_button")
@AndroidFindBy(id = "SEND")
private MobileElement sendButton;
```

Your action code would then be:

```
sendButton.click()
```

More information on these tags and related ones can be found at the [PageFactory library docs](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/pagefactory).

If your IDs did match you could perform your action inline (example below), but I generally prefer to define my elements outside my methods.

```
driver.findElementById("send_button");
```

Everything above can be performed with xpaths as well as other attributes mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Yes it is. I've found it to be the best supported language for Appium.

Answer (score 0):

For android application you can use `uiautomatorviewer` to find element.

Answer (score 0):

Since the same application runs on 2 different platforms, you can have same AccessibilityId if your project have that luxury(means both ios and android developers work on that). 
Otherwise having the same logical test script with different object repo/capbilities will help you.

Comment: I don't recommend using AccessibilityId in your app for use in tests. Reason is that user that actually use assistive technology will hear the AccessibilityId spoken, which means that the content should match very closely to the content displayed on the app - and it could change, meaning more maintenance to the test suite over time.